# Lift algebird aggregator to consume (and return) Map

Tags: scala, algebird

The example in the [README](https://github.com/twitter/algebird/blob/develop/README.md) is very elegant:

```
scala> Map(1 -> Max(2)) + Map(1 -> Max(3)) + Map(2 -> Max(4))
res0: Map[Int,Max[Int]] = Map(2 -> Max(4), 1 -> Max(3))
```

Essentially the use of Map here is equivalent to SQL's `group by`.

But how do I do the same with an arbitrary Aggregator? For example, to achieve the same thing as the code above (but without the `Max` wrapper class):

```
scala> import com.twitter.algebird._
scala> val mx = Aggregator.max[Int]
mx: Aggregator[Int,Int,Int] = MaxAggregator(scala.math.Ordering$Int$@78c77)
scala> val mxOfMap = // what goes here?
mxOfMap: Aggregator[Map[Int,Int],Map[Int,Int],Map[Int,Int]] = ...
scala> mxOfMap.reduce(List(Map(1 -> 2), Map(1 -> 3), Map(2 -> 4)))
res0: Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 4, 1 -> 3)
```

In other words, how to I convert (or "lift") an Aggregator that operates on values of type `T` into an Aggregator that operates on values of type `Map[K,T]` (for some arbitrary `K`)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be done fairly easily for `Semigroup` at least. This should be sufficient in the case where there is no additional logic in the "compose" or "present" phases of the aggregator which needs to be preserved (a `Semigroup` can be obtained from an `Aggregator`, discarding compose/prepare).

The code to answer the original question is:

```
scala> val sgOfMap = Semigroup.mapSemigroup[Int,Int](mx.semigroup)
scala> val mxOfMap = Aggregator.fromSemigroup(sgOfMap)
scala> mxOfMap.reduce(List(Map(1 -> 2), Map(1 -> 3), Map(2 -> 4)))
res0: Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 4, 1 -> 3)
```

But in practice, it would be better to start by constructing the arbitrary `Semigroup` directly, rather than constructing an `Aggregator` merely to extract the semigroup from:

```
scala> import com.twitter.algebird._
scala> val mx = Semigroup.from { (x: Int, y: Int) => Math.max(x, y) }
scala> val mxOfMap = Semigroup.mapSemigroup[Int,Int](mx)
scala> mxOfMap.sumOption(List(Map(1 -> 2), Map(1 -> 3), Map(2 -> 4)))
res33: Option[Map[Int,Int]] = Some(Map(2 -> 4, 1 -> 3))
```

Alternatively, convert to aggregator: `Aggregator.fromSemigroup(mxOfMap)`